# Python Pause a game with a Key

Tags: python, pygame, key, 2d-games, pause

First of all I want to say sorry for my english. Its not my mother tongue. 
I want to make a 2D Snake Game with python. I also want to press the button "p" to pause the game, and if I press it again, it should go on normaly. My idea was to use the time.sleep command. If p gets pressed it should start to "count" and implementing it into the sleep command. If I would p again it should stop the timer  and also the sleep command. Can someone help me with this, because I can't find something in the internet... I use pygames for the key.

Thank you alot.

Jace

Comment: Make the game first, then it will be easier to think about a pause logic when you have the game working. Perhaps you will use `time.sleep()` or maybe you will just stop processing the game logic and make some pause animation instead? Who knows?

Comment: You should never use `time.sleep()` in pygame. That is an evil function which can cause a lot of problems. Your question is a bit broad at the moment, and it's hard to answer, because you haven't posted any code. Do you have any code written? If you do, please use the `edit` link, at the bottom of your question, to include it. If you don't, I suggest following [this YouTube tutorial series on making a snake game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5F-aGDIYaM&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAjkwJocj7vlc_mFU-4wXJq). The answer below has code from the same tutorial, just on a website.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to pause a game:

```
def paused():

    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        #gameDisplay.fill(white)


        button("Continue",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,unpause)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
```

If you want to bind it to a key, use this:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_p:
        pause = True
        paused()
```

Source: https://pythonprogramming.net/pause-game-pygame/